# AWK duplicate row and replace placeholder

Tags: docker, awk

Im stragling with awk in my docker entrypoint script (alpine busybox).

My target is to pass arguments to nginx upstream servers directive. So I have template file:

```
upstream config {
  ip_hash;
  server $UPSTREAMS:18280;
}

upstream application {
  ip_hash;
  server $UPSTREAMS:18380;
}
.... and so on ....
```

As you can see application and DB isn't in docker (otherwise I would use traefik only).

Final config file should looks like this (base on passed env variable):

```
upstream config {
  ip_hash;
  server node1.somewhere:18280;
  server node2.somewhere:18280;
  server node3.somewhere:18280;
}

upstream application {
  ip_hash;
  server node1.somewhere:18380;
  server node2.somewhere:18380;
  server node3.somewhere:18380;
}
.... and so on ....
```

Problem is that number of "servers" (nodes) can change over the time and usage, for example:

- Running nginx docker container by developer on workstation (1 node)
- Dev environment (1-2 nodes)
- Test env (2 nodes)
- Prod env (3 nodes)
- and so on ...

And my latest try of entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/busybox sh
array=${UPSTREAMS//;/ }
set -- $array

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    server_node=$1
    awk '/\$UPSTREAMS/ { print; gsub("\\$UPSTREAMS", "$server_node")};1' upstreams.template > upstreams.intermediate
    shift
done
```

Thanks for any help :)

PS: Sorry for missing v UPSTREAMS variable content:

```
ENV UPSTREAMS="node1;node2;node3"
```

**WORKING VERSION**

Thanks to [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) I was able to correct script:

```
#!/bin/busybox sh
export UPSTREAMS
export SERVER

upstreams=${UPSTREAMS//;/ }
set -- $upstreams

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    server=$1
    awk -v var="$server" '/\$UPSTREAMS/ { print; gsub(/\$UPSTREAMS/, var)};1' /etc/nginx/templates/upstreams.template > /tmp/tmp \
      && mv /tmp/tmp /etc/nginx/templates/upstreams.template
    shift
done

awk '!/\$UPSTREAMS/' /etc/nginx/templates/upstreams.template
mv  /etc/nginx/templates/upstreams.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstreams.final
.....
```

Output:

```
upstream config {
  ip_hash;
  server node3:18280;
  server node2:18280;
  server node1:18280;
}
```

Many thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Can you change the template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat file
upstream config {
  ip_hash;
  server $UPSTREAMS:18280;
}

upstream application {
  ip_hash;
  server $UPSTREAMS:18380;
}
```

.

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

UPSTREAMS='node1;node2;node3'

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1

awk -v upstreams="$UPSTREAMS" '
    BEGIN {
        numServers = split(upstreams,servers,/;/)
    }
    /\$UPSTREAMS/ {
        orig = $0
        for (serverNr=1; serverNr<=numServers; serverNr++) {
            server = servers[serverNr]
            $0 = orig
            sub(/\$UPSTREAMS/,server)
            print
        }
        next
    }
    { print }
' file > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" file
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh

$ cat file
upstream config {
  ip_hash;
  server node1:18280;
  server node2:18280;
  server node3:18280;
}

upstream application {
  ip_hash;
  server node1:18380;
  server node2:18380;
  server node3:18380;
}
$
```